# define index controller as a default controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I will try to define index controller as a default controller

I will also change `routes.php` file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
```

but it did not work when i define `welcome` or other controller name like `admin` so it will work

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

or

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
```

my url is

> http://localhost/ciDemo/

if `default_controller` is `admin` or `welcome` it will work but `default_controller` is `index` so error will be given

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

if there any way to use `index` controller as a `default controller`

my controller file is bellow:

```
Admin
Index
Welcome
```

Comment: Show us your code of index controller. Issue must be in index controller

Comment: create new page user.php(in view) and  **$this->load->view('user');**  replace in index.

Answer (score 5):

> Controller names
>
> Since your controller classes will extend the main application
>   controller you must be careful not to name your methods identically to
>   the ones used by that class, otherwise your local methods will
>   override them. The following is a list of reserved names. Do not name
>   your controller any of these:
>
> CI_Controller
>
> Default
>
> index

Taken from codeigniter 3 documentation

Answer (score 0):

As @Dale said you can not use some of reserve keywords for controller.
But if you still want to use index controler add **__construct()** in controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();       
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```